# Confused on how an equation is reached from Concrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm reading Concrete Mathematics and trying to understand some of the equations. In particular how the author arrives to a particular solution.

Given:
$$L_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 1$$
the author arrives to this solution for $L_{n-1}$:

$$L_n = L_{n-1} + n = \left(\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+1\right)+n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1.$$

I understand how he arrives to $\left(\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+1\right)+n$, but cannot mathematically understand how he reduces that to the final solution $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\left(\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+1\right)+n=\left(\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n\right)+1=\frac{(n-1)n+2n}{2}+1=...?$